# When 'Age' (column 1) == 1, remove all rows with 'Medal' > 20 or 'Height' < 10, or 'Weight' < 50?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

How do you solve this command in pandas on python

I tried this

```
df=df.drop(df.loc[(df['Age']==1) | (df['Medal']>20) |(df['Height']<10) | (df['Medal']<50) ].index
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'When `Age` == 1', you need use `and` condition

```py
out = df.drop(df[(df['Age']==1) & (df['Medal']>20) | (df['Height']<10) | (df['Medal']<50) ].index)
# or
out = df[~((df['Age']==1) & (df['Medal']>20) | (df['Height']<10) | (df['Medal']<50))]
```